# How do I make emacs indent relative to the beginning of the previous line?

Tags: python, indentation, javascript, ruby-mode, ruby

Here's how `emacs` indents e.g. Python code:

```
a = myfun(b,
          c)
```

I'd like it to be this way:

```
a = myfun(b,
    c)
```

Reasoning? If I later replace `myfun` with `myfunction`, in the first case it becomes:

```
a = myfunction(b,
          c)
```

I can probably use [`aggressive-indent-mode`](https://github.com/Malabarba/aggressive-indent-mode), but not everybody uses `emacs`. If I'd like to contribute to, say, an open source project, I can't just impose it on other people.

Is there a way out? For Python? Ruby? Or Javascript? Any of these?

Comment: What's your setting for `indent-tabs-mode`? Not sure it's relevant here, but maybe.

Comment: I believe `python-mode` sets it to [`nil`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-26.3/lisp/progmodes/python.el#L5297). In javascript buffers it's `t`. In both cases the behavior is as described above.

Comment: The usual solution is to add a newline before `b`. This works in all Python/Ruby/JS major modes.

Comment: Yeah, that solves it to an extent. And there seems to be no way to [override](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-26.3/lisp/progmodes/python.el#L1058-L1063) [it](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-26.3/lisp/progmodes/python.el#L1051-L1057). At least not for Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to stick to the defaults, since:

```
r = my_long_function_name(
    param1, param2)
```

is arguably preferable over:

```
r = my_long_function_name(param1,
    param2)
```

But if you care (Emacs 26.3), for [Python](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-26.3/lisp/progmodes/python.el#L1051-L1063):

```lisp
(eval-after-load "python"
  (lambda ()
    (fset 'old-python-indent--calculate-indentation
      (symbol-function 'python-indent--calculate-indentation))
    (defun python-indent--calculate-indentation ()
      (save-excursion
        (pcase (python-indent-context)
          (`(,:inside-paren . ,start)
           (goto-char start)
           (+ (current-indentation) python-indent-offset))
          (_ (old-python-indent--calculate-indentation)))))

    ;; Alternatively, use advice-add
    ;; (defun my/python-indent--calculate-indentation (orig-fun &rest args)
    ;;   ...
    ;;   (apply orig-fun args))
    ;; (advice-add 'python-indent--calculate-indentation :around #'my/python-indent--calculate-indentation)
  ))
```

For Javascript:

```
(setq js-indent-align-list-continuation nil)
```

For Ruby I tried to monkey-patch the Ruby mode, but by default it uses [`smie-indent-line`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-26.3/lisp/emacs-lisp/smie.el#L1783). Which in its turn might be used not only by the Ruby mode. And I didn't see a better way than to copy the `smie-indent-keyword` and fix a thing or two. But I'm far from understanding how it works, so I decided to go with the [Enhanced Ruby Mode](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-26.3/lisp/emacs-lisp/smie.el#L1783). After installation, you need to add:

```lisp
(require 'ruby-mode) ;; https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59782/autoloaded-variable-overrides-the-one-from-the-init-file#comment93779_59782
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (mapcar
       (lambda (x)
         (if (eq (cdr x) 'ruby-mode)
             (cons (car x) 'enh-ruby-mode)
           x)) auto-mode-alist))
(setq interpreter-mode-alist
      (mapcar
       (lambda (x)
         (if (eq (cdr x) 'ruby-mode)
             (cons (car x) 'enh-ruby-mode)
           x)) interpreter-mode-alist))
```

Then to fix the indentation:

```lisp
(setq enh-ruby-deep-indent-paren nil)
```