# Autoloaded variable overrides the one from the init file

Tags: autoload, ruby-mode, ruby, enh-ruby-mode

I added the following line to my init file to replace `ruby-mode` with `enh-ruby-mode`:

```lisp
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (mapcar
       (lambda (x)
         (if (eq (cdr x) 'ruby-mode)
             (cons (car x) 'enh-ruby-mode)
           x)) auto-mode-alist))
```

But it works only for the first file. The first `ruby` file I open is in `enh-ruby-mode`. But in the process the following command is executed:

`/usr/share/emacs/26.3/lisp/progmodes/ruby-mode.el.gz`:

```lisp
;;;###autoload
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
             (cons (purecopy (concat "\\(?:\\.\\(?:"
                                     "rbw?\\|ru\\|rake\\|thor"
                                     "\\|jbuilder\\|rabl\\|gemspec\\|podspec"
                                     "\\)"
                                     "\\|/"
                                     "\\(?:Gem\\|Rake\\|Cap\\|Thor"
                                     "\\|Puppet\\|Berks"
                                     "\\|Vagrant\\|Guard\\|Pod\\)file"
                                     "\\)\\'"))
                   'ruby-mode))
```

(The same line is in `/usr/share/emacs/26.3/lisp/loaddefs.el`.) Which means the second and the following files are opened in `ruby-mode`.

I guess to remedy this I've got to not change the line in `auto-mode-alist`, but add one. Anyways, how does this autoload thing work? When does `loaddefs.el` get executed? Is there a way to keep the line out of the file?

Comment: This looks like a land grab to me: it should be up to the users to set `auto-mode-alist` as they see fit. I would open a bug report. In the meantime, you can force the autoload with `(require 'ruby-mode)` in your init file and then hack `auto-mode-alist` to your heart's content.

Comment: @NickD Can you possibly explain how it works? Without requiring `ruby-mode`, how does `emacs` know that it has to update `auto-mode-alist`? Okay, probably from `loaddefs.el`. But is it a generated file? When does the generation happen? When is `loaddefs` executed? And why does requiring `ruby-mode` solve it?

Comment: My guess is that when `emacs` is built, `ruby-mode`'s [`add-to-list` call](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/progmodes/ruby-mode.el?h=emacs-26.3#n2412) is copied to `loaddefs.el`. As such when `emacs` starts `ruby-mode` is set up to be used for ruby files. But it also provides for `ruby-mode` function to be autoloaded. Then when I change `auto-mode-alist`, something triggers the function, `rube-mode.el` gets loaded, and the line is back in `auto-mode-alist`.

Comment: @NickD You might want to check out my answer. Also, if you're going to file a bug report, please add a link here afterwards.

Comment: I don't use ruby or ruby-mode or enh-ruby-mode, so I'm not going to file a bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing can be reproduced with `expand-region` package installed.

From what I can see, when `enh-ruby-mode` gets activated, `expand-region` loads `enh-ruby-mode-expansions.el`. But that in its turn loads [`ruby-mode-expansions.el`](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el/blob/ea6b4cbb9985ddae532bd2faf9bb00570c9f2781/enh-ruby-mode-expansions.el#L33), which requires [`ruby-mode.el`](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el/blob/ea6b4cbb9985ddae532bd2faf9bb00570c9f2781/ruby-mode-expansions.el#L40).

As a result, when you open a ruby file, `enh-ruby-mode` gets activated, but still `ruby-mode.el` is also loaded.

So, if I change `auto-mode-alist` in my init file, then when I open a ruby file, `ruby-mode.el` gets executed, and adds the association with `ruby-mode` back.

To avoid that one has to require `ruby-mode.el` in advance (before opening ruby files).